# OBSOLETE: React: setState for primitive value doesn't work with ===

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, primitive

EDIT: Obsolete, I made some mistake in another piece of code and the received data had the wrong data type.

I have a variable that stores the index of a selected item. I used a conditional expression based on that variable to add/remove a class name so said item is rendered in a distinguishing way. I boiled down the problem to this snippet:

```
function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = setState(-1);

  setSelectedItem(0);
  console.log(selectedItem);

  return (
    <>
    {selectedItem !== 0 && <p>no item selected</p>}
    {selectedItem === 0 && <p>item {selectedItem} selected</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

This snippet always displays that no item is selected.

Comment: What is `setState`?  Did you mean to use `useState`?  If so, once you correct that error then the next error you'll find here is "too many re-renders", since you're triggering a re-render on every render.  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: @David `useState` of course. This is not what I use in my code, just a boiled down version. The problem is merely with the conditional rendering itself.

Answer (score 2):

The hook is called `useState`, not `setState`.

Calling `setSelectedItem` inside the render function will trigger an infinite loop. You need to move it to an effect hook so it only runs one.

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedItem(0);
  }, []);
  
  console.log(selectedItem);

  return (
    <>
    {selectedItem !== 0 && <p>no item selected</p>}
    {selectedItem === 0 && <p>item {selectedItem} selected</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're right. I change the value in an event handler of course. Didn't think that I need `useEffect` here.

Comment: "I change the value in an event handler of course" — You didn't in the code you provided in the question. Please provide **tested** [mcve]s that demonstrate your problem. Not some untested code that you think will have the same problem as your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

What is `setState` ? Do you mean `useState` ? And also, you shouldn't update the state like this, you should do it in a `useEffect`, and use an empty array as dependency, so it will run only once, when your component is being mounted:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedItem(0);
},[])
```

Then it is working like a charm

Answer (score -4):

Replace `===` and `!==` with `==` and `!=`, respectively, and voila, it works. Alas, a warning is reported that one shall use `===` instead.

`selectedItem` is an array, apparently primitives make bad references. Still, it is bizarre to some extent that inside `<p>` the variable is unboxed automatically, while for evaluating `===` it isn't and thus an array is compared to a primitive, which is not true, no matter the values. `==` compares every shit in JS that you feed it with, so here it works.

Hope, this saves somebody 2 hours of debugging.

If somebody has a correct workaround for this, please share below.

Comment: Why would expect the comparison of an array with a number to ever work correctly? o.O

Comment: Why would expect selectedItem to be an array when initialized with a primitive to be something else but a number?

Comment: "selectedItem is an array" — No, it isn't. The return value from the `useState` hook is an array, but it is destructured with the idiomatic syntax in the code in the question.